# TDBrichedit displays plain text rather than rich text

Tags: delphi, bde

The context is that I am maintaining an application running on delphi 7 with the BDE. I programmatically assign dbricheditcontrols' datafields to allow users to edit rtf documents. When the relevant forms open, the unformatted text is displayed and then once say the person moves onto the next document, suddenly the rich text kicks in; I suspect it must be an initialisation problem of sorts, but what am I missing?

Comment: " I programmatically assign dbricheditcontrols' datafields "  You need to add your code that does this to your q.  You shouldn't expect readers to guess what you are doing.

Comment: Also, be aware that without your code, this q is likely to attract close-votes and once it gets 5, it will be "put on hold" and then no-one can answer it unless it is re-opened.

Answer (score 5):

What you say suggests that you may be going about what you are trying to do the wrong way.  You say you are using a `TDBRichEdit` component, but if you are using it correctly, it should not require any programmatic assignment of datafields to do it: you simply need to connect the component to the TTable or TQuery you are using via a TDataSource component, and configure the DBRichEdit to access whatever field of the TTable/TQuery that stores the richedit text.  That can be done a design time  using the Object Inspector in the IDE to set properties and does not require any code.

So, it seems to me that either you are not using the DBRichEdit correctly, or you are trying to do something that you have not explained in your q.

You can satisfy yourself that a DBRichEdit works automatically, without needing to load or save its contents in code, as follows:

- Open the FishFacts demo
- Add a TDBNavigator and a TDBRichEdit to the form.  Set the `DataField` property of DBRichEdit1 to `Notes`.
- Set the `ReadOnly` property of `Table1` to False.  Then set `Table1`'s `Active` property to True.
- Compile and run the project.  While it's running
- Start WordPad.Exe and create a bit of richtext in it.  Copy it to the clipboard.  Click the `Save` speedbutton of DBNavigator1.
- Paste the richtext into `DBRichEdit1`.
- You should find that you can navigate away from and back to the edited record and the richtext will be automatically reloaded.

Also, the following code works fine for me to load the `Notes` field from an .Rtf file

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Table1.Edit;
  TMemoField(Table1.FieldByName('Notes')).LoadFromFile('D:\test.rtf');
end;
```

and does not initially display the unformatted text as you describe.  So I'm fairly sure you problem is arising in code of yours that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Has this answered your q?

Comment: Sorry about not adding the code. The reason I am programmatically assigning datafields is that I am using a single form to allow the user to view, edit, or post data into one of several fields.

Comment: Sadly not. I want to offer the user a choice between what field is displayed in the data aware control at any one point in time. Using a radio button or tabsheet the user selects which document they wish to work on and it is displayed by changing the value of the datafield property of the TDBRichEdit component: TDBRichEdit1.datafield := <fieldname>. Everything else works except for the first time the form is displayed and the formatting reappears if I switch fields and then back again. Hence I think something is not initiated or a process has not run when the 1st assignment was made.

Comment: Then you really do need to show the code you are using and which demonstrates the problem.  Readers cannnot offer help in a situation like this unless they can reproduce the problem.  And my code works fine for me, even the first time it is run.